# TypeScript doesn't allow to use functions as observer callbacks

Tags: typescript

I have the following working TypeScript code and test:

**menu.service.ts**:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

export class MenuService {
  private events = new Subject();

  public subscribe(next): Subscription {
    return this.events.subscribe(next);
  }

  public next(event?): void {
    this.events.next(event);
  }
}
```

**menu.service.spec.ts**:

```
import { MenuService } from './menu.service';

describe('MenuService', () => {
  let menuService: MenuService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    menuService = new MenuService();
  });

  it('should call a subscriber when an event is fired', function() {
    const subscriber = jasmine.createSpy('subscriber');
    menuService.subscribe(subscriber);
    menuService.next();
    expect(subscriber).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I'm trying to enforce better documentation and coding standards now. One part of this is to add types. So I changed the service:

```
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

export class MenuService {
  private events = new Subject();

  /**
   * Subscribe to events when the menu opens.
   *
   * @param next The callback for the subscription.
   * @returns The subscription for the event.
   */
  public subscribe(next: Observer<null>): Subscription {
    return this.events.subscribe(next);
  }

  public next(event?): void {
    this.events.next(event);
  }
}
```

However, now Typescript won't allow me to pass a spy anymore. I tried accepting a `Function` instead, but that made the type checks on `this.events.subscribe` raise type errors.

How can I fix this?

**edit**

The exact error is:

```
Argument of type 'Spy' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observer<null>'. at line 14 col 31
  Property 'next' is missing in type 'Spy'.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Subject` type is generic but you're not specifying the constraint for it.
Try something like this:

```
export class MenuService {
  private events = new Subject<string>();

  /**
   * Subscribe to events when the menu opens.
   *
   * @param next The callback for the subscription.
   * @returns The subscription for the event.
   */
  public subscribe(next: Observer<string>): Subscription {
    return this.events.subscribe(next);
  }

  public next(event?: string): void {
    this.events.next(event);
  }
}
```

Where you should replace my use of `string` with the real type you're using.

---

#### Edit

I'm not sure what is this `Spy` object, but if you're sure that it can by passed then:

```
const subscriber = jasmine.createSpy('subscriber') as (event: string) => void;
```

Comment: Try my revised answer

Comment: Same error, except it complains about `(event: string) => void` instead of `Spy`.

Comment: Oh, right. My bad, `(event: string) => void` is a function not an `Observer`. Are you sure that the `Spy` thing satisfies an `Observer`?

Answer (score 0):

You can get some odd errors about `next() missing` if you import the wrong Observable.

I got some weird errors and I was importing the following by mistake (!)

`import { Observable } from '@aspnet/signalr-client/dist/src/Observable';`

This has a signature of `.subscribe(Observer<T>)` but this became `subscribe(observer?: PartialObserver<T>)` when I switched to using:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
```